# Не удается преобразовать HTML в Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Я использую [html2canvas](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/). Генерирую HTML-код, получаю канвас и сохраняю как картинку.

Все работает, если HTML-код "скриншот" которого нужно сделать находится в "на странице". Но пользователю не нужно видеть непонятный кусок страницы, по этому, я добавил следующий стиль к родительскому div'у:

```
renderDiv.style.position = 'absolute';
renderDiv.style.top = '-1000px';
renderDiv.style.left = '-1000px';
```

Идея была следующей - генерируем HTML в невидимой части страницы, делаем "скриншот", отправляем пользователю. Но если генерировать скриншот из дива, который находится в невидимой части страницы - картинка получается пустой!

Как можно решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в `position: absolute` (также не будет работать с `position: fixed`)

Попробуйте так:

```
var clone = renderDiv.cloneNode(true);

var style = clone.style;
style.position = 'relative';
style.top = window.innerHeight + 'px';
style.left = 0;

document.body.appendChild(clone);

html2canvas(clone, {
    onrendered: function(canvas){
        //document.body.appendChild(canvas);
        document.body.removeChild(clone); 
})
```